# Initialize user session at Windows Server startup

Tags: windows, command-line

My company uses Windows Server 2019 Datacenter. I have a scheduled task that runs a Jekyll reporting server, which keeps the command prompt open to output any error messages. I also have a service account that anyone on the IT team can log into to view errors when errors occur.

The scheduled task will only display the command prompt if the service account is already logged in when the task executes. If I choose "Run whether user is logged on or not" then cmd doesn't display for the service account.

**Is there a way to write a script or Powershell command to automate logging into the server as the service account?**

The idea is to create the session so that the scheduled task can be changed to run on the service account and have the cmd window appear. The service account is not a default account, and I'd rather not change registry settings to make it so. Wanted to figure out an easy way before editing Jekyll code and dumping errors to error logs.

Comment: Do you wish to have an auto-login that runs automatically when the server is booted and runs CMD? This would be rather easy.

Comment: @harrymc I don't believe my manager would approve of the computer being auto logged in. Wouldn't that make it so anyone using the physical computer wouldn't have to enter a password? I was hoping to just create the user session on the computer for the prompt to display, then people still had to use the password to log in and view it. But I can't find anything on how to do that, so a better approach may be to just spit out an error log that multiple people can view concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Autologon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon). This tool saved an encrypted password, but allows your machine to autologon (hence the name) upon restart. This initiates the user session.