# Start user session without logon upon restart

Tags: login, windows-server-2019, autologon

I've seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1810443/initialize-user-session-at-windows-server-startup/1833686#1833686) but I have a specific requirement: I need to have a windows server machine start the user session after a restart without unlocking the user screen.

The reason for that is that I need a lot of stuff to run automatically on a machine that requires a user session and this machine needs to restart every day. I use a VMWare cloud provider for this machine. If I were to use autologon, the provider would have access to this machine's desktop without being prompted a password, this doesn't happen If I connect via SSH or RDP (the provider gets asked for a password). I believe that if I were able to start a user without logging the user, that would solve this problem.

Comment: What's the difference between your solution and auto-logon?

Comment: @harrymc : From the question: If I use autologon, a person with the equivalent of physical access to the machine (my cloud provider) has access to the machine with it being already logged in (I discovered this recently). If I could start a session but keep the user profile locked, this problem is solved. I am considering the possiblility of adding a task that will lock a session upon start.

Comment: FYI, there's no way to prevent someone with physical access from breaking into the computer, if he's just able to search the internet for the solution. It doesn't even require much hacking capabilities.

Comment: @harrymc There is no way to build a burglar-proof vault, hence why vaults are graded by time required by a professional to break in, people don't just ditch vaults anyway. I've had my share of headaches trying to break into my own computer whose password I had lost (and whose drive was encrypted) to believe it is safe enough for me. As it stands now, it is just too easy for my cloud provider (whom as far as I know, is no big concern as well).

Comment: Why don't you just define a screen-saver with password?

Comment: @harrymc: I sometimes RDP into the machine and cannot leave a wait time too short for the screen saver. And once I RDP-connect, even the user with physical access is prompted a password, so that is okay.

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to have a scheduled task running repeatedly that:

- Checks if no SSH session is running and locks the screen
- Detect that SSH is running and unlock the screen.

For detecting an SSH session, see the post
[Powershell alternative to Unix who command to show ssh sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66850029/powershell-alternative-to-unix-who-command-to-show-ssh-sessions).

The task could be written using PowerShell.
The following command from this post will detect an SSH session:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'sshd.exe'" | Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_SessionProcess | Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_LoggedOnUser | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne 'SYSTEM'}
```

For locking the screen you could use
[nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)
with the command `nircmd.exe monitor off`, or
[Display Power Off Utility](https://sourceforge.net/projects/doff/)
with `doff.exe /l`.

The scheduled task could be set to run every minute, as it's not
very resource-demanding.
A similar test could be done for an RDP session.